# Go : format struct for javascript (json without keys)

Tags: javascript, json, time, go, struct

I have to form a slice of structs for the chart. Marshal it, and return to the frontend widget. 
Widget is waiting for the format like this :

```
[["1455523840380",1],["1455523840383",2],["1455523840384",3]]
```

But My data comes like this :

```
[{"Time":1.45552462158e+12,"Value":1},{"Time":1.45552462158e+12,"Value2},{"Time":1.45552462158e+12,"Value3}]
```

My struct that is coming to the slice is made like this :

```
type ChartElement struct {
    Time  int `json:""`
    Value int `json:""`
}
```

I have now 2 main troubles:

1. how to make the json without keys, but just 2 values with comma
   between  them?
2. how to convert date or time to the javascript
   miliseconds correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output format you want:

```
[["1455523840380",1],["1455523840383",2],["1455523840384",3]]
```

In JSON it is not an array of struct, but an array of arrays.

Since the "internal" array has various types (string and numeric), you can model it like this:

```
type ChartElement []interface{}
```

And you can populate it like this:

```
s := []ChartElement{{"1455523840380", 1}, {"1455523840383", 2}, {"1455523840384", 3}}
```

And if you marshal it to JSON:

```
data, err := json.Marshal(s)
fmt.Println(string(data), err)
```

Output is what you expect:

```
[["1455523840380",1],["1455523840383",2],["1455523840384",3]] <nil>
```

And the time values such as `1455523840380` are the the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 UTC. In Go you can get this value from a `time.Time` value with its [`Time.UnixNano()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UnixNano) method and dividing it by `1000000` (to get milliseconds from nanoseconds), for example:

```
fmt.Println(time.Now().UnixNano() / 1000000) // Output: 1455526958178
```

Note that in order to have time values as strings in the JSON output, you have to add these time values as `string`s in the `[]ChartElement`. To convert this millisecond value to `string`, you can use [`strconv.FormatInt()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatInt), e.g.

```
t := time.Now().UnixNano() / 1000000
timestr := strconv.FormatInt(t, 10) // timestr is of type string
```

Comment: Man, you saved me a great amount of time, Thank you so much!! Hope  that other people would be as helpful for you!!!